# python selenium webdriver cannot figure how to find the element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

[image]

I want to click on the object in a red rectangular which is something if I click on it, it starts downloading the some content(excel file)

```
<a href="#" class="btn_a _excelDownloadBtn _click(nmp.seller_admin.order.n.sale.delivery.excelDownload()) _stopDefault"><span><em class="excel">전체주문 엑셀다운로드</em></span></a>
```

the object is written like this. I'm quite newbie in coding and have not so much knowledge.
When I faced some problems finding the object in selenium, I used firefox selenium builder. But this one doesnt record anything strangely.

So I tried to find it by myself

I tried (1):

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/p/a[3]/span/em').click
```

which is, on Chrome, right click and copy xpath

and I also tried(2):

```
wd.find_element_by_link_text("전체주문 엑셀다운로드").click
```

and (3):

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/p/a[3]/span/em').click
```

and (4):

```
wd.find_element_by_class_name('btn_a_excelDownloadBtn_click(nmp.seller_admin.order.n.sale.delivery.excelDownload())_stopDefault').click
```

when I tried this, I got some different error message which is

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal class name was specified

anchor tag is # which I don't know what it is and, cannot figure out how to click it....

is there anyone who can give me some idea what that object is? why cannot I click it? and how to click it?

Comment: spaces between classes on number 4? or `wd.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'btn_a _click(nmp.seller_admin.order.n.sale.delivery.excelDownload())')]")`?

Comment: Try this `wd.find_element_by_css("._excelDownloadBtn em").click()`

Comment: @TarunLalwani unfortunately, failed again

Comment: Error or doesn't click?

Comment: @jmunsch Thank you for your reply. I tried it just now and failed too...

Comment: error. unable to locate element

Comment: I don't know why it has spaces between classes but I just copied the html. however, I tried both(with and without spaces)

Comment: share the URL..

Comment: I can't. because it needs sign in

Comment: try this css locator: a[class*="excelDownloadBtn"] manually in browser devtool to see it can only find the button you want.  Then try wd.find_element_by_css_selector('a[class*="excelDownloadBtn"]').click();

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it should work for you

```
element = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/p/a[3]/span/em')
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: Cannot find the element

Comment: did you check if this is inside iframe?

Comment: Thank you Kapil, thanks to you, i looked for the concepts of iframe and now I figure out how to switch to frame. My solution is finally this

    wd.switch_to.frame("__naverpay")
    wd.find_element_by_link_text("전체주문 엑셀다운로드").click()

and it works!!!